# LinkedIn oauth2 url one or more urls are not allowed

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

We integrated our application with LinkedIn for sign on over 6 months ago and it's been working fine.  Today, we went to developer.linkedin.com for our application to update the "OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs" to add an additional URL.  We previously had the production domain, test domains, and localhost entered.  Now, when we save, we receive the "One or more urls are not allowed." error message.  Through process of elimination, it appears to not approve our test domain "relode-dev.azurewebsites.net".

I've checked with SURBL and none of the domains we're entering are blacklisted.

Can someone explain why "relode-dev.azurewebsites.net" is no longer valid when it was for 6 months?

Comment: Have you tried asking LinkedIn ?

Comment: This can often be attributed to domains getting black-listed for spamming or other malicious reasons in the time between the initial registration and now().  Check to ensure your domain is not actively listed on the popular SMTP black lists.

Comment: Linkedin support says to post here with tag linkedin.  https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/stacking-api-support-linkedin

Comment: As noted in the question, I checked SURBL and we're not blacklisted.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting some more, it looks like LinkedIn doesn't allow any *.azurewebsites.net domains any more.  I'm not sure why they created this policy.  For now, the workaround seems to be adding your own custom domain to your Azure website and using it in the LinkedIn OAuth 2.0a Redirect URL. You can follow the article at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/ to set up your custom domain.

If LinkedIn reads this, it would be nice if you notified third-party developers when you make policy changes like this.  We've had to scramble for the past few days to workaround this change.

edit: fixed the url to the azure help page (it had an extra word on the end causing it to 404).